# Native Browser Automation using Appium 1.2.0.1 on Windows 7 Android real device: Could not find a connected Android device

Tags: android, maven, selenium, appium

I have looked many forums for this issue, there are quite a few answers on this topic but none of these have worked for me/match my criteria.

I recently took up Mobile Automation task and hence am completely new  to Appium. I am working with Appium 1.2.0.1 on Windows 7 and trying to automate the native Android Browser(not Chrome or an App) on an Android v4.3 real device. 
I have installed everything according to the instructions. I am using Selenium in Maven Build in JUnit Framework to execute the scripts through Appium. I use Appuim.exe in Admin mode and use the GUI to start the node. Then I run my scripts.

My issue is that when I try "adb devices" in cmd, I am able to see the device. Whereas, during execution, Appium is throwing an Error "Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Could not find a connected Android device." I tried many troubleshooting options and verified if everything is in place. No luck. Please help.

Below is the trace of Error:

```
> Checking if an update is available
> Update not available
> Starting Node Server
> info: Welcome to Appium v1.2.0 (REV e53f49c706a25242e66d36685c268b599cc18da5)
> debug: Non-default server args: {"address":"127.0.0.1","fullReset":true,"logNoColors":true,"platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"18","automationName":"Appium","browserName":"Browser"}
> info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:4723
> info: LogLevel: debug
> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"platformVersion":"4.3","browserName":"Browser","platformName":"Android","device":"Android","deviceName":"Android"}}
> debug: Appium request initiated at /wd/hub/session
> info: Retrieving device
> warn:  code=ENOENT, errno=ENOENT, syscall=spawn
> debug: Request received with params: {"desiredCapabilities":{"platformVersion":"4.3","browserName":"Browser","platformName":"Android","device":"Android","deviceName":"Android"}}
> debug: The following desired capabilities were provided, but not recognized by appium. They will be passed on to any other services running on this server. : device
> debug: Looks like we want chrome on android
> debug: Creating new appium session fa19e382-c178-4e6b-8150-a386a51bee39
> debug: Preparing device for session
> debug: Not checking whether app is present since we are assuming it's already on the device
> debug: Checking whether adb is present
> debug: Using adb from C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
> debug: Trying to find a connected android device
> debug: Getting connected devices...
> debug: executing: "C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices
> debug: Could not find devices, restarting adb server...
> debug: executing: "C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" kill-server
> warn:  code=ENOENT, errno=ENOENT, syscall=spawn
> warn:  code=ENOENT, errno=ENOENT, syscall=spawn
> debug: Getting connected devices...
> debug: executing: "C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices
> debug: Could not find devices, restarting adb server...
> debug: executing: "C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" kill-server
> error: Error killing ADB server, going to see if it's online anyway
> debug: Getting connected devices...
> debug: executing: "C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices
> debug: Could not find devices, restarting adb server...
> warn:  code=ENOENT, errno=ENOENT, syscall=spawn
> warn:  code=ENOENT, errno=ENOENT, syscall=spawn
> debug: executing: "C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" kill-server
> warn:  code=ENOENT, errno=ENOENT, syscall=spawn
> error: Error killing ADB server, going to see if it's online anyway
> warn:  code=ENOENT, errno=ENOENT, syscall=spawn
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 20314.056 ms - 206 
> debug: Getting connected devices...
> debug: executing: "C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices
> debug: Cleaning up appium session
> error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Could not find a connected Android device.
> debug: Error: Could not find a connected Android device.
>     at ADB.getDevicesWithRetry (C:\Selenium\AppiumForWindows-1.2.0.1\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\adb.js:600:15)
>     at androidCommon.prepareActiveDevice (C:\Selenium\AppiumForWindows-1.2.0.1\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\android-common.js:349:12)
>     at null.<anonymous> (C:\Selenium\AppiumForWindows-1.2.0.1\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\android-common.js:289:26)
>     at C:\Selenium\AppiumForWindows-1.2.0.1\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:610:21
>     at C:\Selenium\AppiumForWindows-1.2.0.1\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:249:17
>     at iterate (C:\Selenium\AppiumForWindows-1.2.0.1\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:149:13)
>     at C:\Selenium\AppiumForWindows-1.2.0.1\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:160:25
>     at C:\Selenium\AppiumForWindows-1.2.0.1\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:251:21
>     at C:\Selenium\AppiumForWindows-1.2.0.1\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:615:34
>     at androidCommon.prepareEmulator (C:\Selenium\AppiumForWindows-1.2.0.1\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\android-common.js:339:5)
> debug: Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Could not find a connected Android device.)","origValue":"Could not find a connected Android device."},"sessionId":null}
```

And here is my code:

```
if (runEnv.equals("Android")) 
        {
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
              capabilities.setCapability("device","Android");
              capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","Android");
              capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
              capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "Browser");
              capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.3");

              try {
                driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
```

Please help!

Thanks,
Arpitha

Answer (score 0):

Please modify your code with the below one, hope so it works

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
   capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
   capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","sony xperia Z");
   capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4");
   capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
   capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.calculator2");
   capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.calculator2.Calculator");
   driver = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Comment: I tried it, its still the same! I'm stuck at a point where Appium is not communicating with the device.

Comment: Is the application , apk file installed in the device?. Possible options are either your device is not getting detected or there is an issue with adb. Just try to connect the device first and click "Launch" in appium and check if the app is getting installed in device.

Comment: No I do not see anything being installed on the device when I start Appium in Admin mode with the device connected through USB. Whereas when I execute adb devices, I can see it listed. Appium is not talking with ADB I guess..Not sure what else can I do. All my set up is as per the instructions. I have installed Node.js and ANT.as well.

Comment: And FYI, I do nt use any app, I just want to automate the Android Native browser.

Comment: Sorry i didn't notice the details well , let me be clear. You are trying to automate the chrome application which you say as Android's native browser right?

Comment: I guess this link might help you https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/mobile-web.md

Comment: How do I resolve adb issues? Also, does admin rights matter here? I run Appium as an Admin but is there anything else I need to know about?

Comment: What is the version of the android device you are using ? appium suports devices with version 4.1+

Comment: Check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24785692/appium-could-not-find-devices-restarting-adb-server

Comment: @Vignesh : how to modify the capabilities when we are using a protractor code with jasmine framework? because i have the same error in appium but i'm not using java .

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "4.4");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android Emulator");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");
```

Change the Device_Name to "Android", this might work.

Answer (score 0):

In the deviceName field copy and paste the id given in the cmd window when you run the adb devies command.